# Consulta Firebase realtime en android con java

Tags: java, android, firebase

**Tengo una clase para realizar consultas a firebase realtime, en esta tengo una función que realiza una consulta la colección Town**

Intento realizar la consulta para revolver todos los elementos de la colección y en un ciclo for adaptarlo al objeto Town.

*Objeto Town*

Por cada iteración y creación de un nuevo objeto, va llenando un ArrayList, todo esto dentro de un try catch.

Clase de consultas

```
public class AuthenticationRepository {
    private Application application;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private List<Town> dataTownLis = new ArrayList<>();

    private void startFirebase(){
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(application.getApplicationContext());
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    }
     public void devuelveDatos (){
        startFirebase();
        databaseReference.child("Town").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot date : snapshot.getChildren()){

                        try{
                            Town tw = date.getValue(Town.class);
                            dataTownLis.add(tw);

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(application, "A ocurrido un error"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

El objeto Town hereda de una clase padre con elementos de tipo String y esta tiene un atributo de tipo ListArray,

```
public Town(String pui, String name, String description, String latitude, String longitude, String state, List<String> attraction) {
        super(pui, name, description, latitude, longitude);
        this.state = state;
        this.attraction = attraction;
    }

    public String getPui() {
        return pui;
    }

    public void setPui(String pui) {
        this.pui = pui;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setAttraction(String attraction){
        this.attraction.add(attraction);
    }

    public List<String> getAttraction(){
        return attraction;
    }
}
```

[image: Muestra este mensaje de Toast]

Comment: En alguna parte intentas convertir un ArrayList a String. Convendría ver una captura con la estructura de tus datos en Firebase, así como la clase `Town`.

Comment: El objeto extiende desde una clase padre, con elementos de tipo String y esta tiene una propiedad ArrayList<String>

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionar tu problema?